# What is the Team Provisioning I have from scratch?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I understand the provisioning profiles something like this: a provisioning profile contains signing identity information, and used to sign an application code. I can develop an application using simulators without any provisioning profiles. To run and test an application on real devices, I need at least development provisioning profile. These profiles should be generated in Apple Developer Portal and then downloaded to use them locally with Xcode. Currently Xcode itself is responsible for generating and downloading profiles, and Xcode does it automatically. There are also distribution provisioning profiles Ad-Hoc and AppStore.

But I'm confused by so-called "Team Provisioning Profile" used to sign the application in Xcode by default. It appears automatically and allows me to install application on the real devices, so I understand it as an automatically generated development provisioning profile. But I can't see any corresponding iOS-development provisioning profile in the Apple Developer console.

My question is: What is the Team Provisioning Profile then? If it's kind of Development Provisioning, why can't I see it on Apple Developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Team** : - A kind of Development profile that’s managed by Xcode. Xcode automatically adds everyone’s cert to it and all UDIDs from devices as well.

**What is the Team Provisioning Profile then?**

> **To save you time**, Xcode creates and manages a type of development provisioning profile, called a team provisioning profile, for you. The team provisioning profile allows all your apps to be signed and run by all team members on all your team’s devices. For an individual, the team provisioning profile allows all your apps to run on all your devices. Xcode also performs configuration steps for each app service you enable that requires some type of provisioning. Although Xcode simplifies this process, it helps to understand your code signing and provisioning assets and to know where they reside.

***If it's kind of Development Provisioning, why can't I see it on Apple Developer console?***

> **Xcode creates a team provisioning profile** and its components as needed in your developer account. Xcode requests a development certificate for you if it’s missing. The development certificate is used in the team provisioning profile to identify you. A device must be registered to create a provisioning profile, so Xcode may ask you to connect an iOS or tvOS device. For Mac apps, Xcode automatically registers the Mac that is running Xcode.**that's why you can't see it on Apple Developer console**

More check this : [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html)

Comment: I'm aware of this docs, but I can not understand how you came to the conclusion that automatically generated provisioning should not be visible in the Apple Developer console.

Comment: Yea . It is team provisioning profile you aware your team and Xcode generated provisioning profiles automatic that is the reason it is not visible apple developer console

Comment: Team :  A kind of Development profile that’s managed by Xcode. Xcode automatically adds everyone’s cert to it and all UDIDs from devices as well . that's the reason it is not visible  apple developer console

Comment: best practice .. move to another question   .. there will provide my answer if i can ?